# "Typed," vs "typed in"

Tags: grammar

For example:

> I opened Google. Then, after giving it some thought, I typed (in):
>   lolcats.

Should I include the **in** in cases like this. Why?

Comment: I agree, except in the example given both read well, like synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *typed in* for input into a search engine or thing that will use that as a query, and *typed* for things like word processing.